# Have an add-on for Firefox like NoScript, but for cookies (that make possible to whitelist while surfing the web)?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, cookies

I have NoScript installed on Firefox, that blocks every script on pages. I have to manually allow any scripts that are run on my browser.

I would like to have a similar add-on like NoScript, but for cookies: blocks everyone, but shows a list of blocked cookies that I can manually permit.

There is an "exception" tab on Firefox Cookie's preferences, but it isn't what I'm looking for: I would like to whitelist as I'm navigating as NoScript does.

Is this possible? Is there an add-on like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using **[Cookie Monster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-monster/)** -- does the job and somehow similar to NoScript (the toolbar button, can temporarily allow cookies, 3rd party cookies etc).

[image]

Comment: I was looking EXACTLY for something like this. I'm just going to wait a little more if someone posts another plugin or have something to say about Cookie Monster before marking your answer as accepted. :)

Comment: I found problems with redirect loops, where, say, authentication systems need to set cookies to succeed, but you won't get the domain in the list as it is not in use by the current page. How do you deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly as friendly as a NoScript button, but there is the option to allow/disallow cookies per-site via Firefox's `Page Info` dialog. This is accessed by right clicking the background of the page you want to allow/disallow and clicking `View Page Info`.

There may be an addon that simplifies this task, but if not, it would be trivial to write as all of the work is already done.

Comment: The `View Page Info` approach is indeed better than reaching preferences, still not the solution I'm looking for, but at least is a Plan B. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Ghostery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghostery/).

It blocks cookies and also allows you to whitelist domains.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very lightweight extension you can use in conjunction with built-in settings:

[Toggle Cookies](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/toggle-cookies/)

Click the icon to toggle the `cookieBehavior` preference, that's all it does.
When it enables cookies, it intentionally still disallows third party cookies unless you right-click the icon to toggle the `thirdparty.sessionOnly` preference (status will show in a tooltip when hovering over the icon).

This extension is primarily for people who like to keep cookies disabled unless it breaks a site, never want permanent third party cookies, and probably have the "Ask me every time" option selected to control exceptions like a whitelist (tip: that option is more bearable when you set the about:config pref `network.cookie.alwaysAcceptSessionCookies` to true for less repetitive prompting)

Bonus: Middle-click the icon to open your cookies list in a new tab.

Here's an existing per-site cookie settings tip (built-in to the browser) on any page:

- right-click -> View Page Info
- click on Permissions tab
- view or change the Set Cookies options directly