# addon asking to allow cookie or not

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Have an add-on for Firefox like NoScript, but for cookies (that make possible to whitelist while surfing the web)?](https://superuser.com/questions/333107/have-an-add-on-for-firefox-like-noscript-but-for-cookies-that-make-possible-to)

I'm looking for a Firefox plugin/addon/extension that would ask me each time a site wants to set a cookie. With an option to remember my choice.

There are lots of cookie related plugins when I search Firefox repository, but evaluating all of them just to see that there's no such thing would not be a very good idea.

If there's nothing available I will consider making one myself :)

Comment: I've just tried it - and no, unfortunately it doesn't ask me anything, you have to manually define the rules, by going to the site first

Comment: Did you also try the extension mentioned in the second answer, Ghostery?

Comment: ok, I'm following the test yourself path :) it's much better - telling you what it found and blocked, but still it doesn't ask you either, and is an overkill if you only need to block cookies